# How to count a character position in an external file in C

Tags: c

I'd like to know how I could accomplish determining the position of a user-defined character in a stream, that was generated as follows:

User input: number1, number2 (number of random characters in a row, number of rows)

Then I invite a function that should return the position value of the character's first occurrence in the file, if not present then 0.

Here's my code, but it keeps giving me 0 as length of the file.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int charFirst(int *file, char ch);

int main() {
    int row, charcount, i, j;
    char c;
    FILE *fp = fopen("string.txt", "w");
    srand(time(NULL));
    scanf("%d, %d", &row, &charcount);
    for (i = 0; i < charcount; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
        for (j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            fprintf(fp, "%c", rand());
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    //scanf("%c", &c);
    charFirst(fp, c);
    return 0;
}

int charFirst(int *file, char ch) {
    int len = 0;
    *file = fopen("string.txt", "r");
    len = lseek(file, 0, SEEK_END) + 1;
    printf("%d", len);
}
/*  while(!feof(file))
    {
        fscanf(file,"%c");
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Did you read the warnings the compilers yells at you? All these warnings should be considered as errors

Comment: I did, I am trying to get them fixed, but to no avail...

Comment: Fix them and/or ask _specific_ questions about the ones you don't understand.

Comment: What do you mean "to no avail"?  Does that mean that the compiler warned you that you were trying to pass a `FILE *` to a function that expected an `int *`, and you tried changing the parameter type to `float **` but the compiler still complained?  What was the actual warning and how did you try to fix it?

Comment: Of course it's telling you the length of the file is zero. Almost certainly the call to `fseek` is failing and returning -1.  Since you are adding 1 to the value returned by `fseek`, you get `len == 0`.   But there's no need for you to determine the length of the file!  Read the file one character at a time until you've either found the desired character or reached the end of the file.  You don't need to know the file size.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That is actually [`lseek`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html).